# Create Date Object MongoDB new php driver

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7, mongodate

I'm trying to create Date Object to create a document in MongoDB with PHP.

I saw in PHP documentation `new MongoDate()` but I'm using the 'new' drivers MongoDB for PHP7 ([this doc](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/)) and I can't use this.

I tried with MongoDB\BSON\Date but I got `Class 'Date' not found`

I searched across the new driver documentation & stackoverflow but nothing ...

Does anyone know how to create Date Object with the 'new' php driver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the class is `\MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php